# Panda's Write CSV - Append vs. Write

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to use pd.write_csv to write "filename" (with headers) if "filename" doesn't exist, otherwise to append to "filename" if it exists.    If I simply use command:

```
     df.to_csv('filename.csv',mode = 'a',header ='column_names')
```

The write or append succeeds, but it seems like the header is written every time an append takes place.

How can I only add the header if the file doesn't exist, and append without header if the file does exist?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Not sure there is a way in pandas but checking if the file exists would be a simple approach:

```
import os
# if file does not exist write header 
if not os.path.isfile('filename.csv'):
   df.to_csv('filename.csv', header='column_names')
else: # else it exists so append without writing the header
   df.to_csv('filename.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

Answer (score 65):

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, mode='a', header=f.tell()==0)
```

it will add header when writes to the file first time

Comment: I agree this is clean. `df.to_csv(f,mode='a', header=not f.tell())` would also work.

Comment: Do we really need `with open(filename, 'a') as f:` here?

Comment: @JingnanJia due to using `f.tell()` which returns the current position of the file read/write pointer (in this case using append mode reports non-zero if there is content already present), yes you need `with open()`

Comment: In my setup, this creates an additional EoL at the end of each record (one created by the open(), and one created by the pandas writer (which is probably undesired).

So, with open(filename, 'a', newline = '') as f:
etc, etc

Answer (score 11):

In Pandas dataframe "to_csv" function, use header=False if csv file exists & append to existing file.

```py
import os

hdr = False  if os.path.isfile('filename.csv') else True
df.to_csv('filename.csv', mode='a', header=hdr)
```

Comment: Hi VK, what exactly does your answer bring that Padraic's (the most upvoted and accepted one) doesn't? I'd also argue the accepted answer is much clearer.

Comment: I actually like this one. It is easier to read.

Comment: what about `df.to_csv('filename.csv', mode='a', header= not os.path.isfile('filename.csv'))`?

Comment: I like your approach! I went with `file_exists=os.path.isfile(path)` and `df.to_csv('file.csv', mode = 'a', header=not file_exists)`

Answer (score 5):

The above solutions are great, but I have a moral obligation to include the pathlib solution here:

```py
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path(filename)
if file_path.exists():
   df.to_csv(file_path, header=False, mode='a')
else:
   df.to_csv(file_path, header=True, mode='w')
```

Alternatively (depending on your inlining preferences):

```py
file_exists = file_path.exists()
df.to_csv(file_path, header=not file_exists, mode='a' if file_exists else 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from file exist check, you can also check for non zero file size. Since it will make sense to add header if file exists but file size is zero i.e file without content. I find it helpful in some exceptional cases

```
import os.path
header_flag = False if (os.path.exists(fpath) and (os.path.getsize(fpath) > 0)) else True
df.to_csv(fpath, mode='a', index=False, header=header_flag)
```

Answer (score -1):

In case if you have `dict()` and want **to write and append into CSV** file :

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'data.csv'

my_dict = {"column_1":"Apple","column_2":"Mango"}

with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  
  df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
  df.to_csv(f, mode='a', header=f.tell()==0)
```