# Pandas only exporting 1 line to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I'm new to python and am trying to scrape data from a website. The code below returns the information I'm looking for however when trying to export the data to CSV it only includes the last line of the DataFrame. I think it's because when writing to the dictionary it replaces the last row of data scraped but I'm not sure how to avoid this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "http://elite.wttstats.pointstreak.com/boxscore.html?gameid=3149470"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
table = soup.find_all('table', {'class' : 'table nova-stats-table table-    
striped table-hover'})[0]
tbody = table.find('tbody')
rows = tbody.find_all('tr')[1:]

hockey = []
data = {
    '#' : [],
    'name' : [],
    'G' : [],
    'A' : [],
    'PTS' : [],
    'S' : [],
    'PIM' : []
    }

for row in rows:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    data['#'] = cells[0].find(text=True)
    data['name'] = cells[1].find('a').find(text=True).strip("\t")
    data['G'] = cells[2].find(text=True)
    data['A'] = cells[3].find(text=True)
    data['PTS'] = cells[4].find(text=True)
    data['S'] = cells[5].find(text=True)
    data['PIM'] = cells[6].find(text=True)
    hockey = pd.DataFrame([data])
    print(hockey)
    hockey.to_csv("Hockey Data.csv", columns = ["#", "name", "G", "A",         
    "PTS", "S", "PIM"])
```

Here is a sample of the hockey DataFrame returned from `print(hockey)`.

```
#  A  G PIM PTS  S           name
0  3  0  0   7   0  0  Stadel, Riley
#  A  G PIM PTS  S           name
0  4  0  0   0   0  0  Harding, Adam
#  A  G PIM PTS  S             name
0  10  0  0   0   0  0  Brickler, Tyler
#  A  G PIM PTS  S          name
0  11  0  0   2   0  0  Inglis, Kris
#  A  G PIM PTS  S               name
0  12  1  0   0   1  0  Lévesque, Gabriel
#  A  G PIM PTS  S            name
0  14  0  0   0   0  0  Cownie, Jordan
#  A  G PIM PTS  S                 name
0  17  1  0   0   1  0  Mimar, Marc-Olivier
#  A  G PIM PTS  S           name
0  19  0  1   0   1  0  Jensen, Jimmy
#  A  G PIM PTS  S              name
0  23  2  0   2   2  0  Andersson, Johan
```

Comment: Well you construct a new df for every row and write to the same location so only the last row survives. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to extract the data from a table, store it in a dictionary, covert to a DataFrame  and then export it to CSV.

Comment: Well one thing you could do is in your loop change the `to_csv` params so if it's the first iteration write the row with headers, for each subsequent iteration don't write the header and set the mode to append but I don't understand what the result is supposed to look like

Comment: The results should come out as each player and their stats on a different row with the headers at the top. How would I go about adding an iteration to the `to_csv`?  Apologies for the noob question, I am very new to this!

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991541/pandas-write-csv-append-vs-write

Comment: Many thanks for that! It now exports the file in the format I need.