# Only writing first line to CSV - don't understand why

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, zip

I need to convert multiple JSON file to a CSV file. I have a data.zip folder that contains 2000 .JSON file. I am able to load the JSON file and print the data inside each JSON file with print normalized. But when I write it to CSV it only shows 1 line of data. How do I write all the .JSONS data tot he CSV file.

```
import zipfile
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def get_text():
    with zipfile.ZipFile("data.zip", "r") as z:
         for filename in z.namelist():
             with z.open(filename) as f:
                  data = json.load(f)
                  normalized = json_normalize(data)
                  print normalized
                  normalized.to_csv('data.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: Can you give one Jason example?

Comment: ZIP: https://file.town/download/ghoqe6aytuo2ed49o91it5sg8

Comment: I'm confused. What is JSONS?

Comment: JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). It is a data file format.

Answer (score 2):

Default for .to_csv is to write a new file. You need to append - mode='a'. See:

[Panda's Write CSV - Append vs. Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991541/pandas-write-csv-append-vs-write)

Comment: Thank you so much. I spend 12 hours debugging this. You are life saver.

Answer (score 0):

As some people explained you're overwriting your CSV file instead of appending it. Try appending and only writing headersThe first time around.

Here's an example:

```
def get_text():
    add_csv_header = True
    with zipfile.ZipFile("data.zip", "r") as z:
         for filename in z.namelist():
             with z.open(filename) as f:
                  data = json.load(f)
                  normalized = json_normalize(data)
                  print normalized
                  normalized.to_csv('data.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig", mode='a', header=add_csv_header)
                  add_csv_header = False
```