# Dask merge and export csv

Tags: python, merge, bigdata, dask

I have several big `CSV` files more than 5GB, which need to merge. My `RAM` is only 8 GB.
Currently, I am using `Dask` to merge all of the files together and tried to export the data frame into `CSV`. I cannot export them due to low memory.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
file_loc_1=r"..."

file_loc_2=r"..."

data_1=dd.read_csv(file_loc_1,dtype="object",encoding='cp1252')
data_2=dd.read_csv(file_loc_2,dtype="object",encoding='cp1252')

final_1=dd.merge(file_data_1,file_data_2,left_on="A",right_on="A",how="left")

final_loc=r"..."
dd.to_csv(final_1,final_loc,index=False,low_memory=False)
```

If Dask is not the good way to process the data, please feel free to suggest new methods!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pandas dataframe and writing csv files in append mode?

Comment: @RaoSahab pandas cannot read the csv file due to low memory. so i tried to use dask

Comment: If you just merging data, how about reading the file a little bit? more than 50MB less than 100MB recursivly.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv files with pandas.read_csv: setting the chunksize parameter the method returns an iterators. Afterwards you can write a single csv in append mode.

Code example (not tested):

```
import pandas ad pd
import os

src = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']
dst = 'file.csv'

for f in src:
    for df in pd.read_csv(f,chuncksize=200000):
        if not os.path.isfile(dst):
            df.to_csv(dst)
        else:
            df.to_csv(dst,mode = 'a', header=False)
```

Useful links:

http://acepor.github.io/2017/08/03/using-chunksize/

[Panda's Write CSV - Append vs. Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991541/pandas-write-csv-append-vs-write)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html