# How to add/edit text in pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a large file in CSV. Since it is a large file(almost 7 GB) , it cannot be converted into a pandas dataframe.

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('tblViewPromotionDataVolume_202004070600.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
for chunk in df1:
    print (chunk)

df1 is of type pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader

Now i want to edit/add/insert some text(a new row) into this file , and convert it back to a pandas dataframe. Please let me know of possible solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `DataFrame` called chunk, so for processing use it, last for write to file use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with `mode='a'` for append mode:

```
import pandas as pd 
import os

infile = 'tblViewPromotionDataVolume_202004070600.csv'
outfile = 'out.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(infile, sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000) 
for chunk in df1: 
    print (chunk)
    #processing with chunk

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991707/2901002
    # if file does not exist write header with first chunk
    if not os.path.isfile(outfile):
       chunk.to_csv(, sep='\t')
    else: # else it exists so append without writing the header
       chunk.to_csv('out.csv', sep='\t', mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply.

Comment: My question is  : how do i add a line (a;b;c;d;e) for example  as a header to this file which is now a chunk. I am not able to open the file in any text editor as it is a large file. Hence i need to use pandas. I need to add a line on top as a header.

Comment: @nagasatishchilakamarti - How working change `pd.read_csv(infile, sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)` to `pd.read_csv(infile, sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000, names=['a',b','c','d','e'])` if 5 columns in DataFrame?