# Data Frame to CSV

Tags: python

I am currently trying to export my data frame into a csv. The basis of the code is to run a list of tickers through yahoo_fin and get options data. The code works, and I retrieve info for every ticker, however, when I assign the stocks a  data frame to export into csv form, the csv only opens with the last item on the list. Example:

````
stocks = ['AAPL', 'AMZN']

for stock in stocks:

    try:
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        chain = options.get_options_chain(stock, 'October 15, 2021')
        print(chain['calls'])
    except:
        ValueError

    df = pd.DataFrame(chain['calls'], columns=['Contract Name', 'Last Trade Date', 'Strike', 'Last Price', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Change', 'Volume', 'Implied Volatility'])
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\etcetc, index= False, header= True)```

#I am new to python and any help is appreciated! I tried running the data through XlsxWriter and it didn't work either. 

#Thanks!
````

Comment: Do you mean you are only getting the csv file for the last item in list?  If so, it's because your for loop is writing to the same file each time (i.e. overwriting), so you only get the result of the last loop.  One option is to specify a filename based upon the for loop variable (i.e. stock), so the filename will be different with each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df.to_csv` is in the for loop, so it overwrites the previously generated file in every iteration, but the behaviour here should be to append the data at the end of your existing CSV file instead of overwriting.

To do this, you can try writing the CSV with `mode = 'a'` as an argument along with your `index` and `name` parameters, and you have to handle the `header` parameter, as in general, you won't be needing it FOR the append data. You can find a solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991541/pandas-write-csv-append-vs-write)

Alternatively, the preferred way would be to save your data into a dataframe from the loop and write the whole dataframe outside the loop in a single write operation, that way you won't have to worry about handling the header.

Comment: Thanks. I added the mode = 'a' argument to the end of my df.to_csv and I am still having the same issue. What is the mode function doing when it equals 'a'? Wait, that worked. I added the df back into the for loop and I am getting all of the data now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The mode parameter tells how to write to the CSV; the default is `w` mode, which writes(overwrites/creates) a new file every time, setting the mode to `a` will append data at the end of the file, instead of overwriting the existing one. But saving it inside a dataframe and writing it in one operation outside the loop will reduce the write operations, you won't have to worry about the mode or header handling either.

Answer (score 1):

The `df.to_csv` is **in your for loop** so it **writes a CSV file at every iteration.** However, **the name of the CSV file is always the same, so it overwrites the previous file at every iteration**.

Comment: Thanks. So if I get rid of the indentation, will it continually update the csv? What if I defined the data frame by a different variable that included all (chain[calls])? How could I do that?

Comment: No it will not. I would suggest `df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\etcetc' + str(stock) + ".csv", index= False, header= True)` - this will create one file per "stock". I think another reply showed how to put everything in the same file, so i'm just showing how to make a file per item.